# How to track print, scan and copy from a network printer?

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have recently installed a network printer in my office, which is accessible by all users in the network.

I want to track the usages, and i know tracking copy is difficult, but at least i want to be able to track who printed ir scanned and how many pages, documents.

I have installed HP M126NW printer.

Please check and advise if this is possible or any alternate way?

Answer (score 2):

How do people print to the printer? Is it simply mapped via IP or added via Windows search and/or Bonjour? Do you have a print server configured? You have potentially a couple of options.

1. Check the web interface for the printer to see what options for tracking they have. Some printers allow you to track print jobs. Usually there needs to be some sort of authentication method though.
2. I don't know if this would work in your environment, but you could install & configure a print server, and enable logging on the server. Have users map the printer from the server, and this would allow you to audit who prints to it and how many pages. Scanning/Copying would likely be difficult, as those are usually done locally at the printer. This would allow you to look at the print services log and see users who print to it and how many pages.